# ?= and \\1 in Ruby regular-expression pattern matching

Tags: ruby

In looking for a way to add commas to large integers in Ruby (e.g., changing `1000000` to `1,000,000`), I came across the following method:

> ```
> .to_s.reverse.gsub(/(\d{3})(?=\d)/, '\\1,').reverse
> ```

It works as expected, but I don't understand what `(?=\d)` and the first `\` in `\\1` do. When I deleted them from the method, i.e.:

> ```
> .to_s.reverse.gsub(/(\d{3})/, '\1,').reverse
> ```

the method still worked. If these are unnecessary, why are they in there?

Comment: Try converting `999` using both methods

Comment: Thanks. The result converting `999` was `,999` with the latter, but the correct `999` with the former. So is `(?=\d)` then specifying that the replacement only happens when the replacement would precede a digit (in the reversed form)? (Switching `\\1` to `\1` didn't make any difference.)

Comment: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Regexp.html tells me that the answer to my question above is yes: `(?=_pat_)` - Positive lookahead assertion: ensures that the following characters match _pat_, but doesn't include those characters in the matched text. So `(?=\d)` checks to see that the next character is a digit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you correctly observed, the backslash is redundant. The code you found is not a good one. You can remove it. But make sure to use single quotes: `'\1'`. Note that this escape is not interpreted as escape by the parser. It is following the special syntax within `gsub`.

The `(?=\d)` makes sure that the target position for inserting a comma is followed (preceded in the original string) by another digit so that `100000` does not become `",100,000"`; you want `"100,000"`.

By the way, as I already said, the code you found is a bad one. Usually, it is done like this:

```
to_s.gsub(/(?<=\d)(?=(?:\d{3})+\z)/, ",")
```

Here, `(?<=\d)` is playing the same role as `(?=\d)` in your code.

For other ways to do it, see the bottom part of [this](http://doc.ruby-lang.org/ja/1.9.2/doc/spec=2fregexp.html).

Comment: Maybe the code came from a Ruby version <1.9 where there was no lookbehind assertion support.

Comment: Even without lookbehind, there are better ways to do it than the one OP found.

Answer (score 1):

`(?=\d)` is the syntax for positive lookahead. Positive lookahead is indispensable if you want to match something followed by something else.  In this case you want to match 3 digits followed by another digit so you can insert the comma.  The first \ in \1 simply escapes the second slash so that you are left with "\1" which is the syntax for the first replacement group, in this case d{3}, so it replaces d{3} with d{3},.

Comment: The only question I have left then is why does the regex work with or without the first slash?  If it needs an escape, shouldn't there be an error when it lacks the escape?

Comment: @user1652620 it needs an escape if enclosed in double-quotes. In single quotes, most backslashes (namely, unless they're escaping backslashes or quotes) are treated as literals.